# For algorithm with T(n) = a2^(kn) solve how long it takes to solve a problem with n=20

Tags: algorithm

I'm having trouble caluculating the time taken for a problem that goes like this:

The time complexity of an algorithm is determined by measurement. In size
of the problem n = 12, we measured the execution time of the algorithm 0.484 s, and at n =14 we measured
9.844 s. We assume that the time complexity of the algorithm T(n) = a2^(kn)

.
Calculate how long the algorithm will take to solve the size problem
n = 20!

Answer (score 1):

If you just want the mathematical analysis instead of a bound,

`T(12) = a. (2 ^ (12.k)) . 12.k` (eq1)

`T(14) = a. (2 ^ (14.k)) . 14.k` (e12)

Divide eq1 by eq2, `a` gets canceled, all you have are `k` and constants. Solve for `k`.

Now, put the value of `k` in eq1 or eq2 to get the value of `a`.

Finally, you have the final form of the function, just plug `n` = 20.

Answer (score 0):

These kind of exercises show a misunderstanding of what time complexity is.

> The time complexity of an algorithm is determined by measurement.

This is cannot be reliably done. Measurement is not a bullet-proof way to determine the time complexity of any algorithm. It can just serve a confirmation of a proof that was given, based on the analysis of the *algorithm*.

> Calculate how long the algorithm will take to solve the size problem n = 20!

Impossible. Knowing the time complexity of an algorithm, and a few measurements, can only help to have a rough estimation of what this time *could* be, but there is no guarantee at all. It could well be 10000s or 90000s, without violating the given time complexity.